# How would I kick all the users that contain a phrase in their name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Whats a good way to find all users to execute a kick on them if they all contained a phrase in their name like "ihatemelons" for example.

```
                let server = message.guild.id
        
        //grab all discord names
        let list = client.guilds.cache.get(server)
        console.log(`All Users In Guild: ${list}`)
        list.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username)); 
        //Regex term to search 
        let re = (/_/ig)
        
        //Search all of them
        let usersFound = list.members.cache.forEach.match(re)(member => console.log(member.user.username))
        list.members.cache.forEach(usersFound => console.log(member.user.username)); 
        
        //What to do with the users that have the phrase in their name
        message.reply(`Found:${usersFound}`)
```

Except I am stuck on where I search because
`let usersFound = list.members.cache.forEach.match(re)(member => console.log(member.user.username))` doesnt work

Comment: Provide your current code, what part are you stuck on?

Comment: @Elitezen I redid some of it can you try to help me with what is wrong?

Comment: forEach is a method, not a property.

Comment: @user15517071 How do I match the regex to every single user that the list finds and then stores those users to kick?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use a regex to find the phrases you don't like, for example if you don't like the word `creepy` in username, you can simply do this:

```
let regex = /creepy/ig
regex.test("creepyUsername"); // Outputs true
```

for more info about regex:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I am confused

Comment: sure, the two slashes are the regex indicators. the word you put between the slashes is the word you wanna find. the i means that the case sensitivity will be ignored and the g tag means that it can search for multiple matches. if you still need more explanations , let me know. if you want to add more words to the regex, you can use | character, for example if you wanna find word bad in the usernames as well, your regex will be /creepy|bad/ig

Answer (score 1):

```js
message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.username.includes('ihatemelons'))
```

Since [`GuildMemberManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache) returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), you can utilise the methods provided by Collection and Map. `Collection.filter()` acts like `Array.filter()`, but returns a `Collection` instead.

---

**Edit**

This works for me:

```js
const members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
let usersFound = members.filter(member => member.user.username.includes('ihatemelons'));

// OR: case-insensitive:

let usersFound = members.filter(member => /ihatemelons/i.test(member.user.username));
// OR
let usersFound = members.filter(member => member.user.username.toLowerCase().includes('ihatemelons'));

usersFound.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
```

Make sure you have enabled the privileged intent for receiving full member lists in the Discord Developer Portal.

Comment: So once I have all the users that contain 'ihatemelons' in a map how would I kick every single one of them?

Comment: You can iterate through each of them with forEach.

Comment: On a side note, discord.js has [comprehensive documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome). It is immensely helpful when you are unsure about how to access certain information from discord.js objects.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working?

        let usersFound = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.username.includes('ihatemelons'))

        usersFound.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username))

Comment: It works for me. Note that `String.includes()` is case-sensitive.

Comment: How would I kick each one? Would I use the code you gave me above and store it in a variable and then call .forEach on that variable?

Comment: I have no reason to believe that you cannot.

Comment: Extra note: You would want to [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) the members first if you want this to work on offline members too.

Comment: What would I put the fetch on?

Comment: `let usersFound = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.username.includes('dylan')).forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username))` doesn't work

Comment: Where is the working example? I still am confused

Comment: Scroll up. I included it in the answer.

Comment: How would I allow it to be case insensitive?

Comment: Updated answer. You can use regex, as suggested by Alixsep, which offers some more flexibility in case you want to add more bad words (but with a slight impact on performance)